# Number of graphs with vertices of only even degree.

Tags: graph-theory

This is an exercise I don't know how to solve, as I am preparing for an exam it would be great if you could help me with it.

> Show that for $n > 0$ a number of graphs with vertices from set $\left\{1, 2, ..., n\right\}$ in which every vertice has even degree equals $2^{\binom{n-1}{2}}$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** This can be proven combinatorially. The problem statement implies that these graphs are in bijection with is the set of all graphs on $n-1$ vertices. Can you find the bijection?